# How to create and restore memory image dump

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory

So, I have a questionably coded application, with a lot of data structures that need to be restored in a particular way.

I have to implement a one off undo, to restore the application to what it was before a very complex operation.

A member of my team suggested to save the file and restore it to ensure that everything gets reverted. Doing that is a very resource intensive and time consuming operation. File saving and loading can take a minute or more with all the parsing and event processing.

So I have this idea: if I could somehow save the memory state, like in a dump file, I could save the image state and revert it if necessary.

Is this possible to do? If so, how?

Comment: Individual apps can't naively do things like hibernate and restore. Only the system can. You need to persist your state to a file somehow. You will have to write the code. Much in the same way as programs like Excel do. And then restore that state. No simple magic avoids the hard yards.

Comment: You say "to restore the system".  Do you mean the state of your process or the state of the entire computer (other processes, the OS, etc.)?  If just your process, this can be done, but it would be a lot of work and probably isn't better than building a real undo capability into your program.

Comment: Hmm, pressed something on the app and gave you a +1 by mistake @AdrianMcCarthy.  Anyway, to answer your question, I meant application state not system state.  Yeah, I figured as much, but my colleague was adamant about the other thing, so I thought I'd investigate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, like Excel does? If you are just referring to saving the programme state to a file, almost any application does that.  I was just looking for a general way of doing something like a hibernate/restore.

Comment: I know that's what you meant and I said that it wasn't possible.

Comment: Why don't you speed up saving the state then? An obvious optimization would be to store application state to a memory file, instead of persisting it to disk. @AdrianMcCarthy: This cannot be done for a single process either. How would you restore a file handle to a file that has since been disappeared? The accepted answer has an entire list of issue which cannot be dealt with in general.

Comment: @IInspectable:  That's why I asked about whether this was about system state or program state.  If system state changes (like a file goes away), then there's not much you can do.  If the concern is strictly about program state (that's not otherwise tied to system state), it could be made to work.  There's not enough information in the question.

Comment: @IInspectable, that is not possible.  In some files, the memory usage can be quite taxed and there is a lot of complexity that I won't go into here that can cause additional issues.  In any case, it is as I suspected.  This isn't a viable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in general. If you tried it, it might fail in subtle and unpredictable ways. Here are a few potential problems:

1. The process might store its process ID and thread IDs. When you restore it, there is no good way to ensure it gets the same IDs.
2. The process might have files locked. There's no way to ensure those files are in the same state.
3. The process might have files open that no longer exist later. Consider temporary files.
4. The process might have sockets or pipes open either internally or even to other processes.
5. The process might have manipulated shared state that communicates with other processes and stopping the process with that shared state in an inconsistent state might disrupt other processes.
6. The process might have a lock on DLLs or other executable files that may not exist identically when you try to restart the process.

There are a lot of other problems as well. Generally platforms that provide application save/restore capability are either very limited in what they let applications do or they require the close cooperation of the applications.